# How to fix the error :'range' object is not callable in python3.6

Tags: python, loops, range

my code looks like:

```
list_var = ['rh','temp','tl','Tt','DPD','PAR']
for L in range(1, len(list_var)):
     for subset in itertools.combinations(list_var, L):
          f = 'inf ~ {} + C(area)'.format(' * '.join(list(subset)))
```

error `'range' object is not callable` jumped up even I changed `len(list_var)` into a number.
Can you identify the problem and fix it?
Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: `range` is probably redefined

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue when assigning the `range` name to a `range` instanciated object:

```
>>> range = range(10)
>>> range(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 301, in runcode
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'range' object is not callable
```

you probably reassigned the name earlier in your code, triggering this exact error.

A quick & dirty fix is:

```
del range
```

Comment: I checked, but I didn't use range anywhere before. And where should I add the `del range` ?

Comment: -1 because this doesn't address the issue. The person mentioned that she/he has not defined 'range' before. I also have the same issue, once I find the solution, I post it her.