# Error : Python Range object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below piece of code in Python 3.6. Any ideas as to why I get the below error:

```
TypeError: 'range' object is not callable.
```

I am using the range to build an NMF collaborative filter plot. Any help is much appreciated. The error is on the below statement.

```
sdrange = range(2,50,2)
```

Full Code -

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from surprise.prediction_algorithms.matrix_factorization import NMF
    from surprise.model_selection.validation import cross_validate
    from surprise import Dataset
    from surprise import Reader

    #read file
    rankings = pd.read_csv('ratings.csv')     

    dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'itemID': list(rankings.movieId), 'userID': 
    list(rankings.userId), 'rating': list(rankings.rating)})
    moviescales = Reader(rating_scale=(0.5, 5.0))
    mydataset = Dataset.load_from_df(dataframe[['userID', 'itemID', 
    'rating']], moviescales)

    sdrange = range(2,50,2)
    rmse, mae = [], []

    for k in sdrange:
       nmf = NMF()
       results = cross_validate(nmf, mydataset, measures=['RMSE', 'MAE'], 
       cv=10, verbose=False)
       rmse.append(np.mean(results['test_rmse']))
       mae.append(np.mean(results['test_mae']))
```

Comment: I still have trouble replicating the issue because of the csv file stuff. I tried just looping through with the range variable you declared and printing and it worked for me. Maybe give this thread a read? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522852/how-to-fix-the-error-range-object-is-not-callable-in-python3-6

Comment: try printing `range`. What does it look like?

Comment: Check if your `range` is actually what you expect, you probably shadowed it's name. Put `assert range is __builtins__.range` before the line that throws the error.

Comment: Thank you all , the ' del range ' did it. Appreciate your help...